# Sigma algebra problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma algebra and $F:=\left\{A\in \mathcal{A}:\mathbb{P}(A)=0 \ \text{or} \ \mathbb{P}(A)=1 \right\}$ , where $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure.I have to prove that $F$ is sigma algebra.I proved the complements property and that $\Omega \in F$.But how should I prove that if $\left\{A_{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset F \Rightarrow \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_{n}\in F$??

Comment: Yes I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of elements of $\mathcal{F}$. If $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=0$ for all $n$, then
$$ \mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)=0$$
while if $\mathbb{P}(A_k)=1$ for some $k$ then
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)\geq \mathbb{P}(A_k)=1$$
and since $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure it follows that
$$\mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)=1$$
In either case we conclude that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: This also hold if we have more than two sets $A_{n}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A_{n})=1$ ?? Because we know that $\mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\Big)\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Solid answer. I was overthinking by trying to use a "continuity from below" argument  on sets $B_n = \cup_1^n A_i$.

Comment: @Jonathan1234 it's a probability measure so $\mathbb{P}(E)\not>1$ for any set $E$ in the sigma algebra.

Comment: @Jonathan1234: Yes, as soon as at $\mathbb{P}(A_k)=1$ for at least one $k$ it follows that $\mathbb{P}(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)=1$.